# Create a file main domain to subdomain

Tags: php

Actually I made a website. I have 2 domains on hosting. I want when a user registers on **main domain** website then a **id.php** file is created according to his **ID** in the **subdomain** of my hosting. **Like this:>>** **https://social.com/users/1.php**
One thing to note is that I have the code to register but no code to create such a file.

1. /htdocs  **main domain folders**
2. /social.com/htdocs/users/ **subdomain folders**

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVQxY.png)

Comment: Files can be created with `fopen` or `file_put_contents`, but creating a PHP script dynamically sounds very wrong - why would you need to do that?

Comment: @HonkderHase This is what I need to do to run my tests. With php I can create files but not in subdomains when registered to main domain. Is it possible to do as I asked in my question?

Comment: If both domains are hosted on the same server: yes, you can (potentially...). If domains are on different servers: no you can't (unless the application has an API for that, or allows file uploads).

Comment: @HonkderHase yeah both domain are hosted on same server...please help...